# Not more than 93 pages

Tags: compiling

My Problem is that the PDF compiling and quick build does not show more than 93 pages (1 page of appendix misses). However, if I write something in between the appendices on that page (94), it appears. Can someone help me, what is the problem there? I doubt that 93 is the maximum page number LaTeX could handle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Identation after chapter header
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/} }
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},
        %belowskip=-10pt,
        %aboveskip=0pt
        singlelinecheck=false
       ]{caption}                           
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parindent}{18pt}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none,
   isbn=false,eprint=false,doi=false,
style=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} % List of symbols
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section} % Spacing before/after (sub-) section titles
{0pt}{16pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{18pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{. }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries} % Title without "Chapter" but Nr. in front

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries       
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  %\bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
  %\hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}
\geometry{
paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
outer=2.5cm, % Outer margin
bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
top=1.5cm, % Top margin
bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
headheight=15pt 
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\setlength{\headsep}{0.4 cm} % Spacing between header and textblock below
%\setlength{\footskip}{15pt}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{0pt}

\begin{document}
```

Here I input chapters via `\input`, appendix comes at end...

Comment: You're right, LaTeX can easily handle hundreds of pages. Unfortunately, you have not provided enough detail for us to even begin to guess what is going on (though some respondents here seem to be remarkably clairvoyant). So please, tell us what kind of system you're on? What OS and TeX distribution at least, unless you're on overleaf or similar.

Comment: Iam using Microsoft Windows 10, iam using Texmaker. Tex just does not want to shows the appendix content beyond page 93, but if I write something it opens a new page. Im confused.

Comment: Okay. I am not a windows user myself, so I cannot help. I'll leave it to those who might, to ask more relevant question to guide you towards some answer. Good luck.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I doubt that it has anything to do with windows. It sounds more as if the appendix is in some code which needs a shipout trigger. But without some code it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Possibly a stray `\end{document}` somewhere.

Comment: Ive given some input, I know its very chaotic Im sorry for that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You may have a point there. So one way to proceed would be to work on a copy of the original and remove most of the text preceding the appendixes and see if the problem persists. Then strip the appendixes themselves down to the barest minimum, and keep removing stuff while the problem remains. If the problem goes away, maybe the reason becomes apparent. If it doesn't, perhaps the result is short enough to post here so we can look.

Comment: @egreg The question then is, how come the problem disappears if he adds some text?

Comment: Did you actually look for hints in the log file? There could be a clue there.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Because the text is added before the stray `\end{document}`?

Comment: Are the appendices also in separate files, handled by `\input`? And when you write something between appendices, do you mean you add text to the main file between the various `\input` statements``

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen No, the appendix is written in the .main file. I can add text between the figure and table environments, then I get a new page ...

Comment: Oh, does the appendix consist only of figure and table environments, and nothing else? That might be the beginning of an explanation.

Comment: It consits of figures and tables only, and /chapter for A, B, and C. The tables and figures are renamed to be A.1, A.2 etc.

Comment: Would it help if I load the appendix via /input as well? What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, probably not. There is something else going on here. Did you say only one page went missing? So most of the appendices are there? Is it the last page of the last appendix that is lost, or the whole appendix? What about the title of the appendix? Is it lost too?

Comment: Its just the whole page. Oh, the title is lost as well in TOC!

Comment: So let me get this straight: You file ends with `\chapter{title of last appendix}` followed by tables and figures, then `\end{document}`, and the last appendix does not appear, unless you also write some text before the last `\chapter` command? (BTW, I fixed the formatting of your source. *Every* line needs to be indented by four spaces or more.)

Comment: When I write text after last /chapter it appears.

Comment: Hmm. I am running out of questions to ask. No idea what is going on. Try removing all the main text, except maybe for one chapter with a couple lines of text in it, and see if the problem is still there. Then remove `\usepackage` lines and rerun to see if the problem persists. Just keep removing stuff as much as you can, all the time checking to see if the problem remains. With luck, you'll end up isolating the problem, either solving it yourself or ending up with something you can enlist others' help with. Sorry not to be able to help further.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with following: I remember, I wanted to prevent the pagebreak before chapters in appendix. I dont know how and where I managed it, but could that be the reason somehow?

Comment: yes, if you redefine \clearpage, you are breaking the final clearpage which force the shipout of the pending floats.

Comment: Oh god... thanks! I redefined it. Thank you all for your time!!! I just have one question maybe you could give me a short hint. I would like the space to be used as efficient as possible in the appendix. It looks a bit weird if only 1 picture is in on one page. Also, in my chapters, Latex can shrink or enlarge distance to textbodies. This may be advantageous but Im not sure how I could change it as easy as possible. Ps. That was the script caused the error then: \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}

Comment: The issue was due to faulty redefinition of essential commands in a part not shown in the provided code